# I require users location for my function but it returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I am trying to make an app that shows items depending on the their location. Unfortunately my code still runs and doesn't wait until i have found the users location. It returns a nil value. How can i avoid this? Is this possible and how can i achieve it. My code is below

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // check if locations eabled
     print("I got here 1")
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        self.locManager.delegate = self
        self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print("I got here 2")
    }
    else {
        print ("Locations not enabled")
    }

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "LoadItems", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

   LoadItems()

}
```

My LoadItems function requires the location to run

Comment: option-click on the symbol `startUpdatingLocation()` and read the `Discussion`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you´re missing out `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`. Add it in your `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() if-statement` and then add these two functions

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   // Here you can call a function when you have a location

   // And stop updating the location if you don´t need it anymore
   locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to find user´s location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

In this way you will make sure that you

1. Have a location when you call your method
2. Throw an error when you don´t have a location

If you want to get lat and long just use the snippet below in `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`

```
let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
lat = String(location.latitude)
long = String(location.longitude)
```

Comment: So i have tried this. But when i call the 'didupdatelocations' i put some print statements to check if it got in there. In my debug console they do not show up, so im assuming it doest get inside. Is there something im missing?

Comment: Have you added the didFailWithError to? It might be that you fail to load the location. @IkeTrout